# Motor choice for a quadcopter, DC coreless or BLDC?

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, drone, quad-copter

Ok, I am planning to build a quadcopter by myself. Almost anyone uses BLDCs with ESCs in the tutorials etc. I wonder why a BLDC is more preferable than a similar DC coreless motor. For example I found a 3.7V 50000 rpm DC coreless motor.

1. Cheaper than BLDCs.
2. No need to ESC, H bridges are more easy to obtain and use.
3. Easier to operate.
4. I am aware a brushed motor will tear by time, however, just ignore
   it for now.
5. Same and even more rpm than a 2400 KV BLDC with a 3S LiPo (2400 * 3 * 3.7)

So, what do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what do I miss?

You miss that coreless motors are only used in the smallest quadcopters where BLDC motors are too difficult to make in such a small size and the simpler controller saves significant weight.

In larger sizes a BLDC motor can have a higher power/weight ratio at higher efficiency with virtually unlimited lifespan, and is generally cheaper.

And while you didn't miss this:-

> I am aware a brushed motor will tear by time,

At the high power levels required, coreless motors don't last long (lifespan may be measured in minutes). That relegates them to toys where long-term reliability is not important.

One more thing:-

> I wonder why a BLDC is more preferable than a similar DC coreless
>   motor.

You will not find a coreless motor that is similar to a typical BLDC quadcopter motor.

Because coreless motors have no magnetic core they need more turns to produce the same rpm, which increases resistance and reduces efficiency at high torque. Also coreless motors generally only have 2 magnet poles, while 'outrunner' BLDC motors typically have 14 poles or more.

The upshot is that coreless motors produce peak efficiency and power output at much higher rpm than multirotor BLDC motors. To get similar performance the coreless motor would have to be coupled to a gearbox, which adds extra weight and expense and is more fragile (some larger size toy quadcopters do use geared coreless motors in order to swing larger props).

Comment: ok, satisfactory reasons, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main one in your list of specs : more RPM = less torque for the same power. So it'll spin a propellor faster but that propellor has to be tiny.

Spinning a large prop slower produces more thrust (lifts a bigger quadcopter) for the same power.

And this isn't about BLDC vs brushed : it's just about sizing the prop and motor to the job you want it to do. Unless it's a tiny quadcopter the 50000rpm motor will be the wrong choice, however it is controlled.

Once you have the right size, speed and power of motor, you can choose BLDC or brushed in that size, speed, power. (I have even taken a brushed motor and made a BLDC out of it).

And BLDC will always be slightly higher performance (as well as longer lasting). But if simplicity matters more than performance, you can probably make the brushed one fly.

Comment: Is it possible for that motor to not to be able to rotate a propeller, wow. So, what could be the proper alternative of a let's say 1000 KV BLDC then? Will a 6V 6000 rpm DC motor be a nice choice? What is the way of making that relation, if not too long to explain here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Wow indeed. What you need comes down to basic physics. Start with the weight of your drone. You need at least that much thrust. In practice, more so it can climb. Divide by 4 since 4 motors. Now choose a prop size (diameter x pitch) and speed that gives you that thrust. Then choose a motor that can supply the torque to drive tat prop at that speed. Power required varies as the cube of the prop speed and the 4th power of the diameter (keeping speed constant) and ...I forget how it varies with pitch. Online calculators are your friend.

Comment: oh, well, I did not know how to calculate thrust, what it depends and what is the formula. But I did not think to look for online tools, that may help. However, in "Then choose a motor that can supply the torque to drive tat prop at that speed. **Power** required varies as the cube of the prop speed and the 4th power of the diameter (keeping speed constant) and " did you mean **torque** instead of power?

Comment: No, I meant power. Therefore torque varies as the square of the speed.